# What's the best solution if you can't work?

Tags: job-description

What's available for me is to work in call centers that have:

1. 24/7 rotational shirts (Disturbed sleeping cycle).
2. Work place is far from my home. 12 hours per day including transportation time. (This adds to the sleep deprivation)
3. No casual leaves, sick leaves, planned leaves, holidays but you have two days off a week as a weekend.

Other jobs in my country are more difficult. If I worked as an electrical engineer in a factory, I would get the same offer with 1 day off only per week.  Other jobs require working for more than 12 hours a day.

What can I do?  I can't find a proper part-time job or any other solutions!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere over here 'street walking' is illegal :-)

Comment: I think we need a location to be able to answer this. However, if the job situation where you live is so bad, maybe it is time to move.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your situation and quesiton? It is really hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere somewhere with high unemployment rate and barely there labor laws / enforcement entities, I'd say. Location tag will help, and more clarity of the question too...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan "just move" is pretty easy to say, but that isn't always an option if the situation is this bad.

Comment: @HugoZink I wrote "maybe" precisely because it may or may not be feasible for the OP. However, even moving closer to the call centers would eliminate the commute time, making that less bad.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find a part-time job or any other solutions!

Then you're not trying or you're setting your sights too high. No place on Earth has both the described conditions and 100% employment.

Many jobs by their nature are only limited hours such as some forms of security etc, although these tend to be more blue collar or even unskilled. There's absolutely nothing wrong with working outside an office. I not only made more money as a forestry worker but since they provided accommodation for a month during some seasons to have me onsite I saved a lot of my earnings that would have gone on rent, transport and food.

There should also be positions which have fixed hours so you're not doing different shifts. Try your local newspaper or labour department for ideas and leads.

Comment: Many non-office jobs require long periods of standing, which can be physically challenging e.g. for those with arthritic knees. Not everyone can do them.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan and many require prolonged periods of sitting... which is a pain in the butt sometimes. But there is invariably something suitable physically even for wheelchair bound people.